# TreeView.Items.Filter Memory Leak, HELP!

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, listbox, virtualization

I'm having this terrible problem, i have a tree view and i'm using the it's Items.Filter to support search options.

My TreeView is also virtualized cuase it contains tones of items and if not virtualized it takes a minute for the UI to load.

My problem is that whenever i set a filter it seems that the memory usage grows by 20M!!!

1. I don't understand why the ListBox won't use the items it already has and why it needs to create new items (i see calls to the child item's constructors)
2. Why the hell won't it release the old UI elements from the memory?!

PLEASE HELP!!!
Gili

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the old UI elements aren't released?
Try calling GC.Collect(); and see if you loose those 20M, this is not considered a good thing to do but it would verify if the UI elements are released or not.

And does it grow 20M each time you set a filter or just the first time?